# Postgres SQL / HQL query structure comparing 2 lists

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, relational-division

I have a table of FridgeContents, a table of Recipes and a table of RecipeIngredients.

```
CREATE TABLE Recipes
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name text
);
CREATE TABLE Ingredients
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  description text
);
CREATE TABLE RecipeIngredients
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  recipe_id bigint REFERENCES Recipes(id),
  ingredient_id bigint REFERENCES Ingredients(id),
  quantity numeric
);
CREATE TABLE FridgeContents
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  ingredient_id bigint REFERENCES Ingredients(id),
  quantity numeric
);
```

I am developing a SpringBoot application with Hibernate, Spring Data JPA, and a postgresql database.

I am trying to construct a query that would return a list of all the Recipes I could make given my current ingredients.

One way would be to pull all ingredients for a recipe in sequence, check them off from my FridgeContents, and return true if the remainder of the RecipeIngredients list is empty, but that sounds inefficient, especially if I had 1000's of recipes.

Would something like this work, and is there some better trick I could employ?

```
Select * from Recipes where id in (
  Select distinct recipe_id from RecipeIngredients EXCEPT (
    Select distinct recipe_id from RecipeIngredients
    where ingredient_id NOT in (
      Select ingredient_id from FridgeContents
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Added the relational-division tag. Only five tags allowed, so I had to remove HQL.

Comment: Do you want to prepare *more than one* recipe from the contents of your fridge ? (not possible in SQL, needs backtracking or some kind of dynamic programming; besides: more than one possible solution)

Comment: For the purpose of this exercise I am only interested in preparing a single recipe, so just want a list of all possible recipes I could make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using joins and aggregation:

```
select ri.recipe_id
from recipeingredients ri left join
     fridgecontents fc
     on ri.ingredient_id = fc.ingredient_id
group by recipe_id
having count(*) = count(fc.ingredient_id);
```

The having clause is essentially saying:  all the ingredients for the recipe are found in the fridge.  Note:  if either the fridge or the recipe could have duplicate ingredients, then you should use:

```
having count(distinct ri.ingredient_id) = count(distinct fc.ingredient_id)
```

Comment: I used this as part of a JPA named query and it works a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double `NOT EXISTS()` construction for relational division. Note: the result will also include recipes with no ingredients at all ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipes r
        -- ## You cannot make a recipe
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM recipe_ingredients ri
        WHERE ri.recipe_id = r.id
        -- ## ... for which any of the ingredients
        -- ## ... is *NOT* available
        AND NOT EXISTS ( 
                SELECT * FROM fridgecontents fc
                WHERE fc.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id
                AND fc.quantity >= ri.quantity
                )
        );
```